# VS2010 Using SQL Server 2000

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2000

Is there a way to use the SQL Model (dbml) builder in VS2010 using SQLServer2000?
It works fine in VSExpress2008 + VS2008 but throws an "Upgrade SQL to 2005" error in VS2010 which seems a tad unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx) (Goto **SQL Server 2000 Support** near the bottom) support is very limited for LINQ-SQL, which means you might have to consider upgrading if you wish to use LINQ-SQL

Comment: the DBML thing works fine, I tend to use it more for dropping Stored procs in as it works pretty well for that.

Comment: To clarify that, DBML Works fine in VS08 with SQL2000 its just VS2010 that seems to opt out. 
Ideally of course work would just update their Database ;o)

Comment: I don't think SQL server 2000 support is "very limited". Works great in my experience, the only problem here is that VS2010 dropped it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of options:

1. Create a 2008 project that's solely for updating the DBML file.  Jump into that project when you want to manipulate the DBML file using the designer.
2. Update the DBML directly (ick!).

Comment: I went for option 3. move everything over to NHibernate and stop relying on VS as much, being at the mercy of Microsofts sales push isn't a good place to be :o)

Comment: You don't need to create a project. You can just open the DBML file with VS2008, update and save.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this same problem and overcame it by creating the DBML file in VS2008 and then just copying it into my VS2010 project.

First I tried creating it using SQLmetal from a VS2010 prompt but the connection information doesn't get persisted then of course you cannot add the connection from the dbml editor as it wont hook up to SQL2000.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same problem and created the DBML in VS2008, then copied the files over to my VS2010 but it doesn't seem to work. Do you need to change anything else apart from coying the edmx?

Comment: no @user441365 I didn't do anything else at all.
Alternatively you could create your data access methods in a VS2008 project dll and include that in your 2010 solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem when I was trying to add a data connection via the server explorer in VS 2010- it says that it only supports connections w/ MS SQL 2005 or greater. I was able to get it to connect with my SQL Server 2000 db by adding the connection by choosing  and selecting ".NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB" as the data source and for the OLE DB Provider ddl choosing "SQL Native Client", then entering the server the db resides on, the security, and the db name.